# Get loaded resource files list from android webview

Tags: android, android-webview, webchromeclient

Is there any way to get the currently successfully loaded and not loaded files from URL into android webview. That is, if I am loading the following,

- 1.js, 2.js, 3.js
- 1.css, 2.css, 3.css

in html page and load the html file into android webview.

I need to list the loaded files in webview and also which are unable to load into android webview. I tried using the **onConsoleMessage()** from **WebchromeClient** which detects only the console error alone. This method not getting the error messages for css image.

Is this possible to list the files from URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the list of resources the WebView is *trying* to load by overriding `WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest` like so:

```
class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
        android.util.Log.i("MyWebViewClient", "attempting to load resource: " + url);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        android.util.Log.i("MyWebViewClient", "attempting to load resource: " + request.getUrl());
        return null;
    }
```

}

Remember that `shouldInterceptRequest` is called on a background thread and so you need synchronize access to any shared data structures.

There is no Java API to find out whether the WebView has successfully loaded a given resource though.

Comment: This is works fine, but I am not able to find shouldInterceptRequest() with 3 parameters.

Comment: @Karthick - what? there is no `shouldInterceptRequest` with 3 parameters, I never said there is one. The second version of shouldInterceptRequest is only available at targetSdk >= 21

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I found that method and learned about it.